# Is $x\mapsto\underset{i\in I}{\operatorname{arg\:min}}\:a_i(x)$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $i\in I$ be a finite nonempty set and $a_i:E\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable. Are we able to show that $$j(x):=\underset{i\in I}{\operatorname{arg\:min}}\:a_i(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable? It should be true, but I don't have any idea how we can prove it.

**EDIT**: Assume ties are broken by selecting the smallest index.

Comment: How do you even assure that the $a_i$ take on minima at all? Also, $\arg\min$ is usually taken to be a set-valued function, so what does it mean for that to be measurable? Or are you always choosing a specific element, if yes, by which method? This needs some additional hypothesis to be a well-posed question.

Comment: @Thorgott Since $I$ is finite, there is a minimum. But I guess you're worrying about ties. Well, if $i,j\in I$ with $a_i(x)=a_j(y)$, I would choose $\min(i,j)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread part of the question. So, just to be clear, your function is supposed to be $I$-valued? If yes, what $\sigma$-algebra is $I$ equipped with?

Comment: @Thorgott $j$ is $I$-valued and $I$ is equipped with $2^I$ (discrete $\sigma$-algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space, $i\in I$ a finite, totally ordered, non-empty set equipped with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra and $a_i\colon E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{E}$-measurable functions for all $i\in I$. Let
$$j\colon E\rightarrow I,\ x\mapsto\min\underset{i\in I}{\operatorname{argmin}}a_i(x).$$
(I am interpreting $\operatorname{argmin}$ as set-valued here.)

The discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $I$ is generated by the singletons $\{i\}$ for $i\in I$, so its suffices to check that $j^{-1}(i)\in\mathcal{E}$ for all $i\in I$. Now,
$$j^{-1}(i)=\{x\in E\colon i=\min\underset{i\in I}{\operatorname{argmin}}a_i(x)\}=\{x\in E\ \colon(a_i(x)<a_j(x)\ \forall j<i)\land(a_i(x)\le a_j(x)\ \forall j\ge i)\}\\
=\left(\bigcap_{j<i}(a_i-a_j)^{-1})((-\infty,0))\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{j\ge i}(a_i-a_j)^{-1}((-\infty,0])\right)\in\mathcal{E}.$$
Thus, $j$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.